# XAMPP Server and HTTP Server not working on new Spectrum Router

Tags: xampp, fileserver

So, a while back I had AT&T as my ISP and during this time I was hosting my XAMPP server just fine, but they raised their prices so I switched to Spectrum as my ISP and they gave me this new SAX1V1S model WiFi 6 router and ever since then I can no longer access my XAMPP or HTTP servers on my home networks. This new router, quite frankly, sucks and has no Advanced Options like Firewalls. etc. Instead of entering the IP to connect and modify the router settings, I had to download the My Spectrum app to allow the port through the router and this still did not fix my issue, as my server still receives a "This site can’t be reached" error. I know the server works as I can connect to it on my phone on my mobile data and on other WiFi networks, but I cannot connect to it on my own home network. Is there a setting in XAMPP where I can fix this? Or is it explicitly tied to my router.

I was expecting it to work accordingly